# cgi/perl/html - what characters to escape when printing into html?

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I got an input file that I need to print directly into an html page.

I did `$inputfile =~ s/\n/<br>/g;` Are there any other special characters I should be aware of maybe other than < and > when printing this $inputfile to html?

Comment: Do you know the character encoding of your input file, and the desired encoding of the HTML file - or is everything in 7-bit ASCII for now?

Comment: I don't know the character encoding of the input file. It could be anything from third party tool log files

Comment: You will not be able to get a *perfect* solution then. However, if you  run something like HTML::Escape as suggested in the answers, then convert the returns as you already are, it should be pretty close for not much effort.

Answer (score 10):

You absolutely should use [`HTML::Escape`](http://search.cpan.org/~tokuhirom/HTML-Escape/lib/HTML/Escape.pm) instead of doing some ill-conceived hackjob which will cause everyone who deals with your code (you included) to curse your name in the future.

It's simple - install `HTML::Escape` via CPAN, then use it thus:

```
use HTML::Escape qw(escape_html);
my $escaped_string = escape_html($string);
```

Note that if you want to preserve whitespace formatting you should use a module to do that, as well, such as [`HTML::FromText`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/HTML-FromText/lib/HTML/FromText.pm) - the above code will not automagically convert line breaks to 
 tags because that's different completely from escaping unsafe characters to HTML entities.